# Topology of $L^2$ space

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, lp-spaces

Cardinality of space of all funcions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is $\beth_2$. However, cardinality of space of all such square-integrable functions, space $L^2$, is $\beth_1=\mathfrak c$, equal to cardinality of $\mathbb R^n$.

So, from set-theoretical point of view, $L^2$ is as big as usual manifolds, which motivates the question:

What are the topological properties of $L^2$ space (with usual topology) and, more precisely, is there any manifold which is homeomorphic to $L^2$?

Comment: What is the meaning of 'topologically equivalent'? It means 'homeomorphic'?

Comment: @tetori Yes, I will edit my question to be more precise.

Comment: Technically, the space of square-integrable functions, not the equivalence classes of functions that is usually built into the definition of $L^2$, also has cardinality $\beth_2$. The actual set of functions is sometimes denoted by $\mathcal{L}^2$. Indeed there are $\beth_2$ many functions that can be defined on an uncountable set of measure zero. All of them are measurable because the Lebesgue measure is complete, and all them can be extended to a $\mathcal{L}^2$ function on the whole line, by mapping every point outside the set to zero.

Comment: Space $L^2$ is topologically "infinite dimensional", so it is not homeomorphic to any finite-dimensional manifold.

Comment: I'll add that since $L^2$ is a topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, it's contractible. ($v \mapsto tv$, for $t$ going from $1$ to $0$, is a deformation retraction onto $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.)